# AWS region considerations for creating ECS ecsTaskExecutionRole via CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

If I manually run an ECS Fargate task via the AWS console, AWS is nice and automatically creates an [ECS task execution IAM role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_execution_IAM_role.html) for me, which I can then even reference in CloudFormation templates, e.g.:

```yaml
ExecutionRoleArn: !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole"
```

This role uses the AWS-managed `AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy`. The above documentation explains how I can create this role via the console or via the CLI. Basically you create this role (or get AWS to create it for you) a single time, and then you can reference it forever in your CloudFormation templates. The `ecsTaskExecutionRole` AWS creates automatically has no reference to any AWS region, nor does the documentation mention any thing about region considerations for the role if creating via the console or via the CLI.

But I don't want to create the `ecsTaskExecutionRole` manually. If I create a new AWS account, I want to simply deploy a new CloudFormation stack without worrying that I have to first go in and manually configure something. (That is, after all, the central *raison d'être* of CloudFormation in the first place!) AWS doesn't tell me how, but after reading the documentation for [`AWS::IAM::Role`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html) I believe it's as simple as the following. (The documentation notes that creating the role via CloudFormation requires me to specify `CAPABILITY_IAM` somewhere, such as using the CLI, but that doesn't seem difficult.)

```yaml
  EcsTaskExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      Description: AWS managed policy role for executing tasks on ECS.
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement: 
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal: 
              Service: 
                - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Action: 
              - sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy
      RoleName: ecsTaskExecutionRole
```

Note that I set the [deletion policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html) to `Retain`. This way all my CloudFormation templates can create the role once as needed—just as AWS itself does when I run an ECS Fargate task via the console—and just leave it there.

However in the documentation I read this foreboding warning:

> Naming an IAM resource can cause an unrecoverable error if you reuse the same template in multiple Regions. To prevent this, we recommend using `Fn::Join` and `AWS::Region` to create a Region-specific name, as in the following example: `{"Fn::Join": ["", [{"Ref": "AWS::Region"}, {"Ref": "MyResourceName"}]]}`.

The [documentation for `CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-iam-template.html#using-iam-capabilities) similarly says:

> If your template contains custom named IAM resources, don't create multiple stacks reusing the same template. IAM resources must be globally unique within your account. If you use the same template to create multiple stacks in different Regions, your stacks might share the same IAM resources, rather than each having a unique one. Shared resources among stacks can have unintended consequences from which you can't recover. For example, if you delete or update shared IAM resources in one stack, you will unintentionally modify the resources of other stacks.

But the `ecsTaskExecutionRole` that AWS creates doesn't indicate any region, and I presume that this role I would create via CloudFormation would be identical to that role. What's the problem?

It is my interpretation that the scary language is simply saying (albeit not so clearly) that I should be careful not to have one CloudFormation template delete the role if it's being used in another region (although I wouldn't want to delete the role if another CloudFormation template in the same region is using it either, so I'm not sure what regions have to do with it). So as long as I use `DeletionPolicy: Retain` when creating the role via CloudFormation, everything should be fine—or as least no worse than using the `ecsTaskExecutionRole` role that AWS creates automatically when I manually use ECS in the console.

Am I missing something? Is there any way creating an `ecsTaskExecutionRole` via CloudFormation using `DeletionPolicy: Retain` would be any different than coaxing AWS to create the same role by running an ECS task via the console? Is there any downside I haven't considered?

Comment: generally the task execution role is specific to the ecs task. your role will have to be the union of all required task parameters.  I recommend you make a dedicated role for each task with only the permissions it needs.  
"Naming an IAM resource can cause an unrecoverable error if you reuse the same template in multiple Regions. "  Most aws services are region specific but IAM is global.  So if you deploy a cfn stack into 2 regions and they both attempt to create the same role weird things can happen.  You can condition on the `${{AWS::Region}}` pseudo parameter or put region in role name.

Comment: Your comment agrees with the documentation, @erik258. But my question is trying to clarify the documentation. AWS itself creates a _shared role_ if I run an ECS task from the console, doesn't it? You seem to be arguing that AWS's action in this case isn't best practice. OK, point well taken. But the question here is, wouldn't the `ecsTaskExecutionRole` AWS creates be subject to the same pitfalls you mention? How is one that I create in CloudFormation any different? That is the question I'm raising. (And "what does 'unrecoverable error' mean?" could be a follow-up question.)

Comment: Or is there something about the CloudFormation creation process that is different than the console or CLI creation process described under the "Creating the task execution (ecsTaskExecutionRole) role" heading at [Amazon ECS task execution IAM role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_execution_IAM_role.html)?

Comment: The way to do this via CloudFormation (IaC) is to create the role with a different name, like `MyApplicationStackEcsTaskExecutionRole` so you know CloudFormation will always need to create it, and you won't have to worry if that automatic role exists or not, and you won't have to worry about any conflict with other CloudFormation stacks or other things in your AWS account that may also create ECS roles.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "shared role" in the sense that some would be shared and others not shared. There's no difference in the one AWS creates automatically, and the one you create through CloudFormation.

Comment: IAM is a global service, when you create a resource like a role in IAM it exists globally, not in any specific region. The warnings in the documentation are just telling you that if you create IAM resources via CloudFormation, and then try to create that stack in another region, you will get an error because of the name conflict.

Comment: @GarretWilson, the issue here is for cloudformation in particular.  If two stacks attempt to manage the same role you can get weird behavior.  This is only if you manage the role in cloudformation, not just refer to it.  "You seem to be arguing that AWS's action in this case isn't best practice." correct.  the default console behavior should not be construed as best practice.  The web console is the weakest part of AWS's offering

Comment: Thanks for all your comments! My takeaway is that managing the role via CloudFormation may bring about extra weird behavior than creating it via other means, and that anyway the AWS approach of creating this one role isn't the best approach for multiple CloudFormation stacks anyway. (If someone wants to write up an answer I can accept it.) I'll update each CloudFormation template to create its own role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments to my question (thanks to everyone who responded), I understand that managing a single account-wide ECS task execution role via CloudFormation may bring about extra weird behavior than creating it via other means. Moreover the AWS approach of creating a single account-wide role for executing ECS tasks isn't the best approach for multiple CloudFormation stacks anyway.

But [recently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75997367) I've discovered that there are other considerations that sometimes make it preferable to create a task execution role *for each service*, not just for each CloudFormation template. For initially after posting this question I was creating a single task-execution role for an entire testing environment and then using that role for various services. But if a service injects passwords from Secrets Manager, you'll need an even more fine-grained definitions.

Here is how you could set up a single ECS task execution role in CloudFormation to be used by all your services:

```yaml
Resources:

  EcsTaskExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-${AWS::Region}-ecsTaskExecutionRole"
      Description: "Role for executing tasks on ECS in region ${AWS::Region}."
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement: 
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal: 
              Service: 
                - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Action: 
              - sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy
```

You could even export that for use in related (e.g. per-service) CloudFormation templates:

```yaml
Outputs:

  EcsTaskExecutionRoleArn:
    Description: The ARN of the IAM role for executing ECS tasks.
    Value: !Ref EcsTaskExecutionRole
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-${AWS::Region}:ecsTaskExecutionRoleArn"
```

That works fine until you need to inject secrets into a service. The AWS managed [`AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_execution_IAM_role.html) allows these actions:

- `ecr:GetAuthorizationToken`
- `ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability`
- `ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer`
- `ecr:BatchGetImage`
- `logs:CreateLogStream`
- `logs:PutLogEvents`

Notice that the `secretsmanager:GetSecretValue` action is not among them. So let's say that you want to want to inject passwords from Secrets Manager for a Spring Boot application to talk to DocumentDB, as explained in [Using Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/secrets-envvar-secrets-manager.html) and illustrated in [Disable Spring Boot Data MongoDB retryable writes in AWS ECS Fargate with CloudFormation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75997367) :

```yaml
          Secrets:
            - Name: SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_USERNAME
              ValueFrom: !Sub "${DbCredentials}:username::"
            - Name: SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_PASSWORD
              ValueFrom: !Sub "${DbCredentials}:password::"
```

This won't work using the `EcsTaskExecutionRole` defined above. You'll need to define a separate role that includes `secretsmanager:GetSecretValue` as explained at [IAM policy examples for secrets in AWS Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconnect/latest/ug/iam-policy-examples-asm-secrets.html). You could go ahead and add `secretsmanager:GetSecretValue` to your custom role, but you probably don't want to let all services have access to the secrets meant for only the other services (i.e. [PoLP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege)). In that case it may be best to define a separate role for each service needing secrets injected. The following example assumes that you're going to be injecting the [`AWS::SecretsManager::Secret`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-secretsmanager-secret.html) `DbCredentials` referenced above (and which is illustrated at https://stackoverflow.com/a/75999386)

```yaml
  ServiceTaskExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub "my-service-${AWS::Region}-taskExecRole"
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement: 
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal: 
              Service: 
                - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Action: 
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: !Sub "my-service-${AWS::Region}-secret-access-policy"
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement: 
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - secretsmanager:GetSecretValue
              Resource:
                - !Ref DbCredentials
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy
```

This sets up the same ECS task execution role shown at the beginning of this answer, with permissions to access *only the `DbCredentials`* secret.

If someone knows how to use a shared `EcsTaskExecutionRole` and just add the permission to retrieve `DbCredentials` on a case-by-case basis without creating a new role, please let me know.

Comment: I have included this information in a complete tutorial I just posted at [_Connecting Spring Boot to AWS DocumentDB with Secure Credentials_](https://www.garretwilson.com/blog/2023/04/24/spring-boot-documentdb-secure-credentials).