# Disable Spring Boot Data MongoDB retryable writes in AWS ECS Fargate with CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-cloudformation, aws-fargate, aws-documentdb

I'm using CloudFormation to deploy a Spring Boot application in ECS Fargate from a Docker image. It uses Spring Boot Data MongoDB to connect to AWS DocumentDB. Since everything is self-contained in the CloudFormation template (i.e. everything is deployed via the template—no copying and pasting or manual provisioning), I inject the DB cluster in the task container definition, along with the username+password from Secrets Manager:

```yaml
          Environment:
            - Name: SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_HOST
              Value: !GetAtt DbCluster.Endpoint
            - Name: SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_PORT
              Value: !GetAtt DbCluster.Port
          Secrets:
            - Name: SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_USERNAME
              ValueFrom: !Sub "${DbCredentials}:username::"
            - Name: SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_PASSWORD
              ValueFrom: !Sub "${DbCredentials}:password::"
```

I just discovered that [DocumentDB doesn't support retryable writes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/functional-differences.html#functional-differences.retryable-writes). So when my ECS task spins up, it says:

> `com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 301: 'Retryable writes are not supported' on server my-db-cluster.cluster-xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "code": 301, "errmsg": "Retryable writes are not supported", "operationTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": xxxxxxxxxx, "i": 1}}}`

The AWS documentation and various other answers are saying to set `retryWrites=False` by switching to the full `SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI` with the [connection URI format](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/) like this:

`mongodb://<username>:<password>@my-db-cluster.cluster-xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/database?retryWrites=False`

That would be something like this in my task container definition in CloudFormation:

```yaml
            - Name: SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI
              Value: !Sub "mongodb://${DbCluster.Endpoint}:${DbCluster.Port}/?retryWrites=False"
```

But it appears that defining the connection URI overrides the username and password environment variables. So now how do I inject the username+password from Secrets Manager into the connection URI in CloudFormation?

Or is there some other way to disable retryable writes in Spring Boot Data MongoDB that still allows me to inject credentials from Secrets Manager?

Comment: You could do something similar to the example at the bottom of the page here: 
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-connection that uses a custom MongoClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer to set the URI. Yours could take in the different spring properties you are setting, and construct the URI string, along with the additional settings appended to the string.

Comment: Otherwise you might need to store the entire URI as a value in SecretsManager, and pass that into ECS as `SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI` in your task's `Secrets` settings.

Comment: `<RhetoricalQuestion>`It amazes me that apparently most people in the world are using (in production) the cute little examples in the books that make it look easy but are not secure. Am I really the first person in the world that has ever tried to connect Spring Boot to DocumentDB on AWS without hard-coding the username and password in the connection string? Really now?`</RhetoricalQuestion>`

Comment: How is placing the username and password in the connection string any less secure than storing them in a few separate strings? They are all strings stored in memory in your application, and passed into the same MongoDB connection provider library. If you have proof that this is somehow insecure, then please cite that proof.

Comment: @MarkB the key phrase is "hard coded". I didn't say that _having_ credentials in the URI was less secure. But the problem is _how they get in the URI to begin with_. I can find no evidence that anyone has actually tried to get them into the URI _from a secure secrets manager_. So how is everyone using Spring Boot on AWS with DocumentDB? How do they get the username/password into the connection URI? Do they deploy their CloudFormation templates via the console and manually type in the password in a parameter field? Do they hard-code it into the CloudFormation or Terraform template?

Comment: "Otherwise you might need to store the entire URI as a value in SecretsManager." But @MarkB I don't manually type secrets into the secrets manager. (That's like so 2013. ) I use [`AWS::SecretsManager::Secret GenerateSecretString`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-secretsmanager-secret-generatesecretstring.html) in CloudFormation to generate a password when the stack is deployed. I never see it or care what it is. Can CloudFormation or Terraform somehow generate a password and then interpolate it into a connection URI in AWS Secrets Manager?

Comment: Neither of my suggestions suggest using hard-coded values. Yes Terraform can definitely generate passwords and then interpolate them into a connection URI in AWS Secrets Manager. I've done this before in Terraform. I don't use CloudFormation so I can't help you there.

Comment: My other suggestion would leave your Infrastructure (CloudFormation) exactly as it is, and simply add another class to your Spring Boot app. You could even use Spring Boot profiles so that the class is only active in your AWS environment.

Comment: "Neither of my suggestions suggest using hard-coded values." @MarkB yes I understand. I was just thinking aloud. From the examples online it would seem that few people use either of your suggestions. I was just wondering aloud if a lot of people actually hard-code the password in practice. Or maybe nobody is using ECS + Spring Boot + Secrets Manager + DocumentDB in production. If they are, I'd be curious how they are doing it. I'm just surprised I'm the first one to try it. Or maybe everyone does it in a corporate setting and don't document publicly how they did it.

Comment: @MarkB thanks for your input. Your suggestion of storing the full connection URI in the secrets manager was clever and might work if one is using an infrastructure as code tool that allows formatted secrets to be dynamically generated. (I'm not sure this is possible in CloudFormation.) And the Baeldung article [Spring Data MongoDB – Configure Connection](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-connection) you referenced appears full of useful information; I'll note it for future reference. However I believe I've found a more elegant workaround for this particular problem; see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you specify the individual Spring Boot Data MongoDB environment variables such as `SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_PASSWORD` (which will be accessible internally via configuration properties such as `spring.data.mongodb.password`), Spring will construct the connection URL dynamically. But if you specify the connection URI environment variable `SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI`, Spring will ignore the individual components, including the username and password ECS has injected from Secrets Manager, as noted in the question.

But there is a workaround to force Spring to pull in the secret credentials you've injected even via the connection URI. Spring Boot provides a facility for interpolating configuration properties dynamically using [property placeholders](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.files.property-placeholders), similar to CloudFormation references except that these references are replaced *at runtime*. So it's possible to go ahead and inject the username and password, and then use placeholder in the actual connection URI, like this:

```yaml
          Environment:
            - Name: SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_HOST
              Value: !GetAtt DbCluster.Endpoint
            - Name: SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_PORT
              Value: !GetAtt DbCluster.Port
            - Name: SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI
              Value: mongodb://${spring.data.mongodb.username}:${spring.data.mongodb.passsword}@${spring.data.mongodb.host}:${spring.data.mongodb.port}/?retryWrites=False
          Secrets:
            - Name: SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_USERNAME
              ValueFrom: !Sub "${DbCredentials}:username::"
            - Name: SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_PASSWORD
              ValueFrom: !Sub "${DbCredentials}:password::"
```

Based on the recommendations the AWS DocumentDB console provides, you might even want to use this extended connection URI:

`mongodb://${spring.data.mongodb.username}:${spring.data.mongodb.password}@${spring.data.mongodb.host}:${spring.data.mongodb.port}/?replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false`

Now username and password are injected into environment variables at deploy time, and Spring Boot itself will plug those values into the connection URI for you *at runtime*.

There is a tiny caveat that is necessary to mention but otherwise inconsequential. If the password were to contain the plain `@` or `:` characters, it would make the `username:password@…` portion of the URI ambiguous, so MongoDB requires those to be URI encoded. Furthermore if you were to include `%`, that character would also need to be encoded because it's the first character in a URI encoding sequence. As Spring Boot has no way of dynamically URI-encoding configuration property references, it's easy enough to tell AWS Secrets Manager to exclude those three characters when generating a password. [`AWS::DocDB::DBCluster`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-docdb-dbcluster.html#cfn-docdb-dbcluster-masteruserpassword) already prohibits the `/`, `"`, and `@` characters, so really you're only removing two extra characters from those available.

Thus you might generate a [`AWS::SecretsManager::Secret`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-secretsmanager-secret.html) like this in CloudFormation:

```yaml
  DbCredentials:
    Type: AWS::SecretsManager::Secret
    Properties:
      Name: db-creds
      GenerateSecretString:
        SecretStringTemplate: '{"username": "somebody"}'
        GenerateStringKey: "password"
        PasswordLength: 99
        ExcludeCharacters: '/"@%:'
```

(Tip: Although DocumentDB claims to support passwords of 100 characters, in reality the underlying RDS will still complain if the password is over 99 characters in length.)

The [Spring Boot Data MongoDB documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.mongo-db-factory.config) says:

> Username and password credentials used in XML-based configuration must be URL-encoded when these contain reserved characters, such as `:`, `%`, `@`, or `,`. The following example shows encoded credentials: `m0ng0@dmin:mo_res:bw6},Qsdxx@admin@database` → `m0ng0%40dmin:mo_res%3Abw6%7D%2CQsdxx%40admin@database` See [section 2.2 of RFC 3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.2) for further details.

However [RFC 3986 § 3.2.1. User Information](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986.html#section-3.2.1) isn't so limited, and can actually contain: `sub-delims` from § 2.2.

> `userinfo    = *( unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" )`

Thus if we exclude the remaining delimiters, i.e. `gen-delims`, from § 2.2, that gives us the following, which is probably most correct and safest:

```yaml
        # exclude `/"@` as per DocumentDB restrictions
        # exclude `%`, the URI encoding delimiter, so the password can be interpolated into a connection URI
        # exclude `:/?#[]@` `gen-delims` from [RFC 3986 § 2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986.html#section-2.2)
        ExcludeCharacters: "/\"@%:?#[]"
```

Comment: That's a very nice solution.

Comment: I just now wrote up and posted a complete tutorial with this information at [_Connecting Spring Boot to AWS DocumentDB with Secure Credentials_](https://www.garretwilson.com/blog/2023/04/24/spring-boot-documentdb-secure-credentials).